# Sort GroupBy object by certain max. value within individual groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sort my groupby object by the highest value for a certain year - i.e. the 2018 values. However, unsuccessfully.
**Code**:

```
aggs = {'sales':'sum')
df.groupby(by=['segment', 'year'].agg(aggs)
```

**Default result** by pandas when grouping
(sorted alphabetically by Level0, then ascending by Level1)

```
Segment Year Sales  
A 2016 2  
A 2017 10  
A 2018 6  
B 2016 1  
B 2017 4  
B 2018 8
```

**Expected result:**

```
Segment Year Sales  
B 2016 1  
B 2017 4  
B 2018 8  
A 2016 2  
A 2017 10  
A 2018 6
```

i.e. A is sorted behind B, because sum of B in 2018 is 8 while for A it is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create ordered `Categorical` with categories by filtered values with `2018` and sorted by `Sales`:

```
cats = df[df['Year'] == 2018].sort_values('Sales', ascending=False)['Segment']

aggs = {'Sales':'sum'}
df['Segment'] = pd.Categorical(df['Segment'], ordered=True, categories=cats)
df1 = df.groupby(by=['Segment', 'Year']).agg(aggs)

print (df1)
              Sales
Segment Year       
B       2016      1
        2017      4
        2018      8
A       2016      2
        2017     10
        2018      6
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!
Interesting, never came across pd.Categorical, particularly the ordered feature.